# Using an NSArray subclass in Core-data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I would like to store a subclass of a `NSArray` as an attribute of a coredata entities.

I have no issue storing an `NSArray` via a transformable attribute. But what ever I try (custom value transformation for exemple) I cannot manage to save/retrieve the attribute as an instance of my NSArray subclas, only as a NSArray.

Does anybody successfully manage something like this and could help me?

As for now I have the following implentation of my class: `Coordinate`

```
@implementation Coordinate

-(double)longitue
{
    return [self[0] doubleValue];
}

-(double)latitude
{
    return [self[1] doubleValue];
}
-(NSString*)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lont %@ lat %@", self[0], self[1]];
}

+ (Class)transformedValueClass
{
    return [Coordinate class];
}

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation
{
    return YES;
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value
{
    return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:value];
}

- (Coordinate*)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value
{
    return (Coordinate*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:value];
}

@end
```

and in my model, `Value transformer` and `Custom class`are set to `Coordinate`

Thanks for your help.

P.S: I know that my class does not need to be an array, but it's just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more tinkering with the issue, it has more to do with subclassing `NSArray` thant with core data.

For now a simple `NSObject`subclass with an `NSArray` as a property will do.